# Why didn't the Jedi use counterintelligence techniques to track down Sidious?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-clone-wars, darth-sidious

I was thinking of this after watching the Clone Wars episode where they find Sifo-Dyas's body and discover Silman, Valorum's old assistant. As Obi-Wan and Anakin are there with Silman, Dooku arrives and kills Silman.

In counterintelligence, if you find there's a leak, you look at everyone who knew that piece of information before the leak. If there's a cluster of leaks, you start looking for commonalities; who keeps showing up when you look at who knew the information before each leak? With this you can get a good idea of who you should look at.

You can then start creating leads and looking at the situation after each leak with particular attention paid to the suspects to try to find proof of a connection. With the investigation into Sifo-Dyas, Count Dooku came to kill Silman right when the Jedi were there; the only explanation is that there was a leak of some sort. They could look at who knew and who's on the list of suspects and start pursuing leads.

Why didn't they try this?

Comment: How do we know they did not?

Comment: They did. They narrowed the list of potential suspects down to The Chancellor and his staff, then proceeded to discount the Chancellor as a suspect.

Comment: ^ +1. The whole premise of RotS and why they wanted Anakin to spy on the Chancellor is because 1) the dark side surrounds the Chancellor 2) therefore they believe Darth Sidious is someone close to the Chancellor 3) Anakin is close to the Chancellor 4) it is said that Anakin will destroy the Sith, not join them, so sending him to find the Sith makes perfect sense.

Comment: Valorum, Only because of the evidence found during the Battle of Coruscant, when they found that only the Chancellor and his staff could have known the info that was leaked (and when it was obvious). My point is they should have been able to narrow it down much sooner during the Clone Wars.

Answer (score -3):

Many of the plot holes to the original trilogy are immediately plugged when one realizes what George Lucas' original vision was: That Jar-Jar was intended to be the true Phantom Menace that is clouding the abilities of the Jedi.  He is the reincarnation of Darth Plaugeis the Wise, who did indeed master death before he was murdered; it is no coincidence that both Jar Jar and Darth Sideous are both from Naboo.  And what do we know about a powerful force user who anticipates and welcomes their death?  *"I will become more powerful than you can possibly imagine."*

If such a thing sounds like a shocking bit of insanity, consider that it was supposed to originally be the big plot twist at the end of the second movie but was changed at the last minute because Mr. Lucas didn't want to risk more fan backlash (when in fact this would have actually redeemed him).

It is difficult to argue that this was not canon once you examine all the facts and evidence, [as this famous (and conveniently anonymous) user presented to the collective Internet recently:](https://www.reddit.com/comments/3qvj6w)

> Consider: We hate the way Jar Jar influences major plot points for the same reason we hate his physicality- it messes with our sense of realism. Two experienced Jedi on a serious mission would never actually bring someone that stupid along with them. No character that idiotic would ever really be made a general. They certainly wouldn't be made a senator. How could anyone like Jar Jar really convince the entire galaxy to abandon democracy? That's ridiculous.
>
> These things are just the political version of his physical "luck." Inadvertent, seemingly comical bumbling that just so happens to result in astoundingly positive results. But what if it isn't inadvertant, and what if Jar Jar's meteoric rise and inexplicable influence isn't the result of dumb happenstance, but the result of extensive and careful use of force mind powers?

In fact, [an entire community has sprung up around the idea](http://www.reddit.com/r/darthjarjar) and there is extensive evidence collected there to support the theory, with even the actor going on record as supporting that the theory was the original intent and he hopes in time this will be incorporated as official canon:

So you may not like the answer, but it apparently is what the author originally intended: they could not, because **their force abilities and thinking were being interrupted and scattered by the most powerful force user in existence: a reincarnated Darth Plagueis**.

Search your feelings.  You know it to be true.

Comment: This answer may not be well-received. It's speculative, without much canon backing. People tend to downvote such things. Besides, Jar Jar has acted quite against his and Palpatine interests, behaved nobly, and a whole host of other things that make this theory improbable.

Comment: Ahmed Best, the actor who plays Jar Jar has gone on record as saying the theory is true: https://youtu.be/ZgJF5hT3Lrg

Comment: Ahmed Best is not the creator of *Star Wars*, nor the rights-holder, nor (crucially) the person who wrote the original trilogy. He's not offering any special insight into the series, merely his own opinion. And who wouldn't want their character to be awesome rather than silly?

Comment: George Lucas, the creator: "Jar Jar is the key to all of this" (https://youtu.be/bz-SaMu8k3w)

Comment: Out of context. I won't downvote, though.

Comment: As we can see here, the official website of the film in 1999 literally called Jar-Jar a menace, and even went to the trouble of using air quotes: http://imgur.com/0471fgM

Comment: Additional support showing that George Lucas significantly altered the plot, which may have (would have) given an concrete and public answer to this question: http://i.imgur.com/FZCL8kX.jpg

Comment: I've downvoted. Silly fan-theories aren't what we're looking for here.

Comment: You have George Lucas himself as well as the actor who played Jar Jar stating that the original plot was significantly changed.  You also have the official website calling Jar Jar a 'menace', and the movies show Jar Jar next to Darth Sideous most of the times he is acting in any official capacity.  There are videos of Jar-Jar mouthing the lines of other characters on screen, many of these videos.  Finally, George Lucas stated that "Jar Jar is the key to all of this".  This is not a silly fan theory.  This is the clear answer, even though it may shock and anger fans.

Comment: Finally, I rest my case with this: from George's own mouth in the Empire DVD commentary:    "Yoda really comes from a tradition in mythological storytelling- fairy tales- of the hero finding a little creature on the side of the road that seems very insignificant and not very important, but who turns out to be the master wizard, or the master thing..."  We know from his own mouth the original trilogy was supposed to 'rhyme' with the OT.  This was the rhyme, and Jar-Jar was the master wizard character.

Comment: P.S. Count Dooku's ship is undeniably in the shape of Jar Jar's face, though that proves nothing solely on its own: http://i.imgur.com/H7iAp2Q.jpg  It is easy to see what George Lucas had envisioned as the climax to the second movie - a dramatic plot twist mirroring Empire's where Jar-Jar reveals himself and has an epic light saber fight with Yoda.  This was changed to a fight with Dooku after the backlash, but the reality of the original intent still propels the events of the OT.